# Writing multiple docstrings, and comments for a random function that was given to me

Tags: python, arrays

Hello I am given a function and I am not sure what function each function does: (Yes that is all I am given)

```
def pumpkin(b1,b2,b3):
    b4= b2+b3
    b5= []
    for b6 in b1:
        if b6[0] == b2 and b6[:2] !=b4:
           b5.append(b6)
        return b5
```

I do know that the if function goes over and the character in position 0 from the list b6 gets compared to the list of b2. the characters from position 0 and 1 from list b6. In order to make the function work b6[0] must equal to b2 and b6[:2] must not equal to b4. Any help will be appreciated.
I need to have docstrings and comments that clarify the user what each function does.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Add comments and docstrings on each function, describing what they do.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is insane, because it's not clear what any types are. However from your description, I think I was able to figure it out. Here is the function again, with "type annotations":

```
def pumpkin(as_in, s2, s3):
   s4 = s2 + s3
   as_out = []
   for s in as_in:
      if s[0] == s2 and s[:2] != s4:
         as_out.append(s)
   return as_out

a = pumpkin(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'], 'J', 'a')
print(a)
```

Where `as_` is an Array of Strings, and `s` is a String. If that is correct, then what the function does is take an array of strings. Then it looks for elements matching a first letter, but not matching a second letter. If I am right in that, then you can actually simplify function like this (among other ways):

```
def pumpkin(as_in, s2, s3):
   as_out = []
   for s in as_in:
      if s[0] == s2 and s[1] != s3:
         as_out.append(s)
   return as_out
```

In either case, with my example the result would be `['Jun', 'Jul']`.